# Error occured in uploading file in php (image)

Tags: php, html, mysql

first of all i would like to apologize for this question because i know there are already a lot of people asked for this matter. but all the answers i searched didn't solve my problem. so hope you consider this question and help me solve this problem.

so basically i am trying to upload an image file and when i submit it, error pops up :

`Warning: move_uploaded_file(./images/jarvs.jpg): failed to open stream:`

`Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\wamp\tmp\phpA25F.tmp' to './images/jarvs.jpg'`

i really dont get the error but i know that the error occurs when im trying to transfer the image from the path of the image and send it to my destination folder (target path)

so heres my code:

**HTML :** 
`<input id="profimagefile" name="profileimage" class="input-file" type="file">`

**PHP :**

```
$targetPath = "images/";
$targetPath = $targetPath.basename($_FILES['profileimage']['name']);

 //name of the file
 $img = $_FILES['profileimage']['name'];
 $size = $_FILES['profileimage']['size'];
 $type = $_FILES['profileimage']['type'];

 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['profileimage']['tmp_name'], $targetPath))
 {
 $queryupload = "INSERT INTO images_profile (image_name, image_path, date_uploaded, emailAddress)
  VALUES ('$img', '$targetPath','$registerDate', '$email')";

 mysqli_query($conn, $queryupload);
 echo "The file ". basename($_FILES['profileimage']['name']). " has been uploaded." . "<br/>";
 }
 else {
 echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file." . "<br/>";
 }
```

dont mind the inserting of the database, its just part of the process after the image is already moved to my targetpath. 
thank you for answering

Comment: Have you given the permissions to folders

Comment: Yes please check the permissions of "images/" folder

Comment: what permissions? i dont understand.

Comment: @JarvisMillan Does the folder `./images/` exist in the first place? Then, list the directoy structure (`ls -lai` on Unix systems) and print the result in your question.

Comment: use absolute path instead of *./images/jarvs.jpg*

Comment: yes ofcourse. i created the folder named images. im using windows 8 and it is really in the directory ( im using wampserver for testing ) and the directory path is : C:\wamp\www\orglounge\public\images

Comment: @donald123 how to use absolute path?

Comment: "folder does not exists" to me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
$targetPath = "images/";
//create folder if not exist
if(!is_dir($targetPath)){
    if(!mkdir($targetPath, 0777, true)){
        die('Failed to create folder.');
    }   
}
//set folder's permissions writale and executable
chmod($targetPath, 0777);
$targetPath = $targetPath.basename($_FILES['profileimage']['name']);

 //name of the file
 $img = $_FILES['profileimage']['name'];
 $size = $_FILES['profileimage']['size'];
 $type = $_FILES['profileimage']['type'];

 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['profileimage']['tmp_name'], $targetPath))
 {
 $queryupload = "INSERT INTO images_profile (image_name, image_path, date_uploaded, emailAddress)
  VALUES ('$img', '$targetPath','$registerDate', '$email')";

 mysqli_query($conn, $queryupload);
 echo "The file ". basename($_FILES['profileimage']['name']). " has been uploaded." . "<br/>";
 }
 else {
 echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file." . "<br/>";
 }
```

Comment: i get it now why it gave me an error, because actually my images folder is not in the same directory where my php file is. 
my images folder is in : "public/images"
while my php file is in : "public/php/saveimage.php"

Answer (score 0):

Try this ::

**HTML**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data>
<input id="profimagefile" name="profileimage" class="input-file" type="file">
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
if(file_exists(__DIR__."/images"){
$targetPath = __DIR__."/images/";
$targetPath .= $_FILES['profileimage']['name'];

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['profileimage']['tmp_name'], $targetPath)){
 echo "Upload success";
} else {
echo "Upload failed";
}
} else {
  echo "Dir images not found";
}
```

Comment: nope, it brought me to else statement, didnt go to file_exists

Comment: Add thisline in your else  echo error num : ".$_FILES['profileimage']["error"];

Comment: Did you get any error code for file upload?. If file is completely uploaded $_FILES['profileimage']["error"] will be zero

Comment: it just gave me "0" - .$_FILES['profileimage']["error"];